# UDP Hole Punching Not Working For A P2P Network

Tags: python, json, sockets, udp, p2p

I am back again with another UDP Hole Punching problem, I seem to have figured out the concept, but I still can not seem to apply it. Apparently, to punch a hole in the NAT you must first send a welcome message (or any message really) first then send the actual data. I am doing this, but it doesn't seem to be working when node to node communication needs to happen.

This code is apart of a P2P chat system I am developing.

```
import socket
import threading
import json

nodes = {}

class Marboo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.bi = ""
        self.bp = 5002
        self.cmds = {
                "checkin":self.checkin,
                "msg":self.msg,

                }
        self.nick = "test"
        self.room = "a"
    def main(self):
        self.get_nodes()
        while True:
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(102400)
            data = json.loads(data)
            print data

    def prompt(self):
        while True:
            msg = raw_input(self.nick+"> ")
            data = json.dumps({"cmd":"msg", "message":msg, "room":self.room, "nick":self.nick})
            self.send(data)

    def get_nodes(self):
        self.sock.sendto("", (self.bi, self.bp))
        data = self.sock.recv(1024)
        nodes = json.loads(data)
        for x in nodes:
            self.connect(tuple(nodes[x]))
            self.sock.sendto(json.dumps({"cmd":"checkin"}), tuple(nodes[x]))

    def send(self, msg):
        for x in nodes:
            self.connect(tuple(nodes[x]))
            self.sock.sendto(msg, tuple(nodes[x]))
    def connect(self, addr):
        self.sock.sendto(json.dumps({"cmd":"connect"}), addr)
    def checkin(self):
        pass
    def msg(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=Marboo().prompt).start()
    Marboo().main()
```

Comment: How are you running this? What is the network setup? What is the question?

Comment: Why question is why this isn't working! I have run it on several different systems, several different ways. It works locally, it's just when I try to receive data remotely, for example from my server.

My problem is that I can not receive data through my firewall because I am doing something wrong when trying to apply this concept.